# How do I name my dvd with imgBurn software

Tags: imgburn

I want to burn a dvd but I don't want it to have the same name as the file on my computer.
Can I give it a name by using imgBurn software (its a freeware I dwnloaded to burn Cd's and DVDs).

I've seen the option first time I used the program. It also prompted me to select the name for the DVD when launched first time. But now its not there and the source is all grayed out(even though I can still select a file to burn) and it doesn't ask me to select a name when I start burning a dvd it just gives it a name (similar to the file on the computer).

Comment: I figured it out. It was a simple mistake when you put in a blank cd you have to click `build and burn` instead of just `burn` img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what type of file(s) are your burning to DVD? There should be a "Labels" tab available during the process of using imgBurn.

[imgBurn guides can be found here](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showforum=4)

.
[image]

Comment: I;ve seen that the first time i used the program. It also prompted me to select the name for the dvd the first time. But now i its not there and the source is all grayed out. (even though i can still select a file to burn) and it doesnt ask me to select a name when i start burning a dvd it just gives  it a name (similar to the file on the computer).

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I found out my simple mistake was clicking `burn` instead of `build and burn`... `burn` function does not let you name your img

Comment: @Xitcod13 you are welcome.